# Kind of cross join query with filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have following three tables:

```
dbo.Product
Id  | Name
1   | P1
2   | P2

dbo.ProductTranslations
Id  | LangId    | Text
1   | 1         | Text_EN
1   | 2         | Text_DE
2   | 1         | OtherText_EN

dbo.Language
Id  | Culture
1   | en-US
2   | de-DE
3   | es-ES
```

I need a query like:

```
select * 
from ProductTranslations pt (some join) Language lang
```

To produce:
for product 1:

```
1   | en-US     | Text_EN
1   | de-DE     | Text_DE
1   | es-ES     | null
```

for product 2:

```
2   | en-US     | OtherText_EN
2   | de-DE     | null
2   | es-ES     | null
```

Ideally I would like to have a view that I can filter on using Id.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.  You want rows for all the languages, even when there is no matching translation.

You can do this with `left join`:

```
select p.productId, l.culture, pt.text
from (select 1 as productId) p cross join
     language l left join
     ProductTranslations pt
     on pt.id = p.productId and pt.langid = l.id;
```

You can just change the "1" to whatever product you like.

If you prefer to use a `where` clause, you can do:

```
select p.productId, l.culture, pt.text
from product p cross join
     language l left join
     ProductTranslations pt
     on pt.id = p.productId and pt.langid = l.id
where p.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.Id
    ,p.Name
    ,l.Id as LangId
    ,l.Culture
    ,t.Text
FROM
    dbo.Product p
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Language l
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductTransalations t
    ON p.Id = t.Id
    AND l.Id = t.LangId
```

Use a Cartesian Join between products and languages to get every possible combination of them, then LEFT JOIN ProductTranslations.

Here is a full working example

```
DECLARE @Product AS TABLE (Id INT, Name CHAR(2))
DECLARE @ProductTransalations AS TABLE (Id INT, LangId INT, Text VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Language AS TABLE (Id INT, Culture VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (1,'P1'),(2,'P2')
INSERT INTO @ProductTransalations VALUES (1,1,'Text_EN'),(1,2,'Text_DE'),(2,1,'OtherText_EN')
INSERT INTO @Language VALUES (1,'en-US'),(2,'de-DE'),(3,'es-ES')

SELECT
    p.Id
    ,p.Name
    ,l.Id as LangId
    ,l.Culture
    ,t.Text
FROM
    @Product p
    CROSS JOIN @Language l
    LEFT JOIN @ProductTransalations t
    ON p.Id = t.Id
    AND l.Id = t.LangId
```